# How to Use BETWEEN and LIKE in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a question about T-SQL. I try constraint for my table. By the way, i want to use BETWEEN and LIKE command. I try this but it doesnt work.

```
 SELECT * FROM
 dbo.GrnStock
 WHERE 
 StockNo BETWEEN LIKE '%823%' AND LIKE '%829%'
```

StockNo is NVARCHAR and has values like:

```
T000578
X000825
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: What do you intend to happen? Please share some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Is StockNo a number or varchar? BETWEEN + LIKE is ambiguous. What codes do you expect to be true for this? Is 9823 between this range? What about 8239999? Please post samples of what you are trying to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If StockNo is a varchar or nvarchar,  then you could get the number part out of it.
Then you'll be able to use `BETWEEN` to compare that number within a range.

For strings like 'T000578' the 6 digit number is at the end.

Then you could do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.GrnStock
WHERE TRY_CAST(RIGHT(StockNo, 6) AS INT) BETWEEN 823 AND 829;
```

But for that range it could probably be simplified with using just a `LIKE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.GrnStock
WHERE StockNo LIKE '%00082[3-9]';
```

Comment: StockNo type nvarchar and not only number include. Ex: T000578

Comment: @MehmetKutlu You should include that information in your question.